# git GUI that has blacklist or whitelist patterns?

Tags: git, gui

The last time I used tortoisegit it didn't support whitelist or blacklist patterns. I couldnt say ignore these generated files (such as objects) which was annoying when I have several dozens projects and folders that I'd like to commit.

What git gui app has the ability to specify blacklist or whitelist file patterns?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it support a special dialog box for it, but it will respect the [`.gitignore` files](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html) you will commit.
Those simple text files can define the whitelists or blacklists you want.

Comment: +1, although `.gitignore` files aren't needed to be committed to work. In fact you can gitignore a `.gitignore` file.